# Cannot link a shared library for python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, gcc, centos7, ld

I make a module for apache, and use gcc for compile:

```
gcc \
    $(apr-1-config --cflags) \
    $(apr-1-config --includes) \
    $(python3.6-config --cflags) \
    -fPIC -DSHARED_MODULE \
    -I/usr/include/httpd/ \
    -c mod_demo.c
```

But when I try to link the python libraries it does not work:

```
ld \
    $(apr-1-config --link-ld) \
    $(python3.6-config --ldflags) \
    -Bshareable \
    -o mod_demo.so \
    mod_demo.o
```

The output message is:

```
ld: -linker not found.
```

What is the problem?. The flags are:

```
[root@demo demo]# python3.6-config --ldflags
-L/usr/lib64 -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

If write the flags without -Xlinker, it works fine:

```
 ld \
    $(apr-1-config --link-ld) \
    -L/usr/lib64 -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -export-dynamic \
    -Bshareable \
    -o mod_demo.so \
    mod_demo.o
```

How to use native flags from `python3.6-config`?, what is the problem for `-Xlinker`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-Xlinker -export-dynamic` is a single thing which tells GCC to pass `-export-dynamic` to the linker.

You are misusing `python3.6-config --ldflags` in the sense that it expects its output to be given to GCC, not to ld directly.

Try this:

```
gcc \
    $(apr-1-config --link-ld) \
    $(python3.6-config --ldflags) \
    -shared \
    -o mod_demo.so \
    mod_demo.o
```